# Were deserts once oceans/seas?

Tags: geology, literature

I was reading *The Alchemist* and stumbled upon something that says, 
[image: The Alchemist, Page 104]

> Here and there, he found a shell, and realized that the desert, in remote times, had been a sea.

Were the deserts once oceans/seas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, some of them clearly were, for example whale fossils have been found in the [Sahara](http://news.wustl.edu/news/Pages/20047.aspx) at the [Wadi al-Hitan](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/1186). However, while some deserts were once oceans/seas, that doesn't mean all deserts were once oceans.